# -webkit support in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, webkit

I am a little new to CSS and CSS animations. I am tired of optimizing my webpages specifically for IE (all versions). Is there some javascript library of something of the same sort that can enable CSS -webkit syntaxes in IE?

I find it easy and good designing for webkit browsers like chrome but IE needs special focus.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A library like [prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) can translate the prefixes, but making older IE actually display the animations is a whole different matter.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it out.

Comment: No, Its not working the way I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Internet Explorer 10 supports some more CSS3 features. Did you to obmit the prefix? If this doesn't work there is nothing you can do. You may need to wait for the Internet Explorer 11.

However I would not recommend to concentrate your work for the IE. Better try to make run your app on Firefox, Safari, Opera and co.

Have also a look to the blog post [Adapting your WebKit-optimized site for Internet Explorer 10](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx) by Microsoft.

Comment: I would be thankful if you can tell me a way to make it work in IE as I am almost done developing my project using -webkit and in case things mess up, I will have to work for IE specifically as most clients still use Windows XP and 7 's inbuilt browsers.

Comment: Well focusing on IE just makes almost every developer crazy. The IE got much better but it is still hard work to make every feature work on it. However the other browsers are IMHO more common and have a much better standards support.

Comment: Yes right, I'll take it as a consolation. My clients use IE, thats the trouble.

Comment: If you have a concrete problem with migrating a CSS feature to IE10 you may ask a second question for that, or you could add it to your currient question.

Comment: Call me lazy, but I don't want to build complete project again just for IE. And even if I gather that courage, I don't think IE will be worth a try as most features are inherently not supported. I wish there exists some javascript which enables IE to parse CSS3 Animations/keyframes and other features.

Comment: You could try to use jQuery this supports many kinds of animations.

Comment: I don't know JQuery, I can only use a pre-made script in my Webpages. Can you tell me any?

Comment: Have a look to this page: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ there you can also download jQuery.

Comment: If this answer helps you feel free to accept my answer. jQuery is prety cool but you should try to do not everything with JavaScript. A really good page uses JS optional.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at css3pie.com it can render as from IE6. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't find it supporting CSS3 animations/keyframes.